# I can find deap in conda list, but cannot import name base in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, python-import, deap

I tried to use DEAP for Multi Objective PSO. So, I installed deap in my anaconda environment using pip install. and I found the deap in conda list.
but I cannot import deap in python. Could you help me to solve this problem?
I activated conda environment before install the package.

my default python path and deap library path is below.

```
'$which python' 
'/sw/model/SMD/conda2/envs/py2/bin/python'

'$whereis deap'
'/sw/model/SMD/conda2/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deap'
```

When I execute my file deap.py, I get the error below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "deap.py", line 5, in 
         from deap import base, creator, tools, algorithms

ImportError: cannot import name base

Comment: Did you activate the conda environment before running your code? Is `deap.py` your file, or from the DEAP package? Please edit your post to add information, and please format file paths and commands more readable.

Comment: I activated conda environment before running the deap.py which is my file.